# How to add variable `df1$DateTime_1` to `df2` when `df1$DateTime_1` match within a 5-seconds interval with `df2$DateTime_2`

Tags: r, data.table, match, tidyverse, lubridate

I have dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df1` summarises different moments (`df1$Theor.DateTime`) in which, theoretically, a device sends info to the satellites. We know that thanks to the variable `df1$Delay`, which indicates seconds-interval among different emissions from the device to the satellites. `df2` summarises specific times (`df2$Real.DateTime`) at which the satellites received info of this device. As you can see in the example below, `nrow(df2)` is smaller than `nrow(df1)` since some emissions didn't arrive to the satellites due to different reasons. You can also see that `df2$Real.DateTime` doesn't match precisely with `df1$Theor.DateTime` due to different reasons. There is always a delay among emission and reception of signal by the satellites.

```
options("digits.secs" = 3)
df1 <- data.frame(Theor.DateTime= c("2018-03-22 12:00:00.000","2018-03-22 12:00:30.040","2018-03-22 12:01:15.800","2018-03-22 12:02:15.700","2018-03-22 12:02:45.350","2018-03-22 12:03:15.002","2018-03-22 12:04:00.065","2018-03-22 12:05:15.430","2018-03-22 12:06:00.060","2018-03-22 12:06:45.002"),
                  Delay= c(30,45,60,30,30,45,75,45,45,60))
df1$Theor.DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df1$Theor.DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC")

head(df1)
           Theor.DateTime Delay
1 2018-03-22 12:00:00.000    30
2 2018-03-22 12:00:30.039    45
3 2018-03-22 12:01:15.799    60
4 2018-03-22 12:02:15.700    30
5 2018-03-22 12:02:45.349    30
6 2018-03-22 12:03:15.002    45


df2 <- data.frame(Real.DateTime= c("2018-03-22 12:00:02.000","2018-03-22 12:02:20.540","2018-03-22 12:02:42.800","2018-03-22 12:05:18.700","2018-03-22 12:06:33.700"))
df2$Theor.DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df1$Theor.DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC")

df2
           Real.DateTime
1 2018-03-22 12:00:02.00
2 2018-03-22 12:02:20.53
3 2018-03-22 12:02:42.79
4 2018-03-22 12:05:18.70
5 2018-03-22 12:06:33.70
```

What I want is to create a dataframe with info of `df1` and `df2` simultaneously. I want to merge in the same row `df1$Theor.DateTime` and `df2$Real.Datetime` when `df2$Real.Datetime` is within a 5-seconds interval (+- 5 seconds) regarding `df1$Theor.DateTime`. I also want to create a column called `Reception.success` that indicates if a specific `df1$Theor.DateTime` has a match with `df2$Real.Datetime` (TRUE or FALSE), indicating that the emission was received.

I would expect that:

```
> df3
            Theor.DateTime Delay Reception.success           Real.DateTime
1  2018-03-22 12:00:00.000    30              TRUE 2018-03-22 12:00:02.000
2  2018-03-22 12:00:30.040    45             FALSE                    <NA>
3  2018-03-22 12:01:15.800    60             FALSE                    <NA>
4  2018-03-22 12:02:15.700    30              TRUE 2018-03-22 12:02:20.540
5  2018-03-22 12:02:45.350    30              TRUE 2018-03-22 12:02:42.800
6  2018-03-22 12:03:15.002    45             FALSE                    <NA>
7  2018-03-22 12:04:00.065    75             FALSE                    <NA>
8  2018-03-22 12:05:15.430    45              TRUE 2018-03-22 12:05:18.700
9  2018-03-22 12:06:00.060    45             FALSE                    <NA>
10 2018-03-22 12:06:45.002    60             FALSE                    <NA>
```

Does anyone know how to get that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `Non equi join` function in `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)

options("digits.secs" = 3)
df1 <- data.table(Theor.DateTime= as.POSIXct(c("2018-03-22 12:00:00.000","2018-03-22 12:00:30.040","2018-03-22 12:01:15.800","2018-03-22 12:02:15.700","2018-03-22 12:02:45.350","2018-03-22 12:03:15.002","2018-03-22 12:04:00.065","2018-03-22 12:05:15.430","2018-03-22 12:06:00.060","2018-03-22 12:06:45.002"),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC"),
                  Delay= c(30,45,60,30,30,45,75,45,45,60))
df2 <- data.table(Real.DateTime= as.POSIXct(c("2018-03-22 12:00:02.000","2018-03-22 12:02:20.540","2018-03-22 12:02:42.800","2018-03-22 12:05:18.700","2018-03-22 12:06:33.700"),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS",tz="UTC"))


df2[,`:=`(minus_5=Real.DateTime-5,
          plus_5=Real.DateTime+5)]


df2
#>             Real.DateTime                minus_5                 plus_5
#> 1: 2018-03-22 12:00:02.00 2018-03-22 11:59:57.00 2018-03-22 12:00:07.00
#> 2: 2018-03-22 12:02:20.53 2018-03-22 12:02:15.53 2018-03-22 12:02:25.53
#> 3: 2018-03-22 12:02:42.79 2018-03-22 12:02:37.79 2018-03-22 12:02:47.79
#> 4: 2018-03-22 12:05:18.70 2018-03-22 12:05:13.70 2018-03-22 12:05:23.70
#> 5: 2018-03-22 12:06:33.70 2018-03-22 12:06:28.70 2018-03-22 12:06:38.70


df1[df2,on = .(Theor.DateTime<=plus_5,Theor.DateTime>=minus_5),"Real.DateTime":=i.Real.DateTime][,"Reception.success":=!is.na(Real.DateTime)]

df1
#>              Theor.DateTime Delay          Real.DateTime Reception.success
#>  1: 2018-03-22 12:00:00.000    30 2018-03-22 12:00:02.00              TRUE
#>  2: 2018-03-22 12:00:30.039    45                   <NA>             FALSE
#>  3: 2018-03-22 12:01:15.799    60                   <NA>             FALSE
#>  4: 2018-03-22 12:02:15.700    30 2018-03-22 12:02:20.53              TRUE
#>  5: 2018-03-22 12:02:45.349    30 2018-03-22 12:02:42.79              TRUE
#>  6: 2018-03-22 12:03:15.002    45                   <NA>             FALSE
#>  7: 2018-03-22 12:04:00.065    75                   <NA>             FALSE
#>  8: 2018-03-22 12:05:15.430    45 2018-03-22 12:05:18.70              TRUE
#>  9: 2018-03-22 12:06:00.059    45                   <NA>             FALSE
#> 10: 2018-03-22 12:06:45.002    60                   <NA>             FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Frank. Just one doubt, should I use `setDT` instead of `data.table` in my real example with hundreds of thousands of rows in both dataframes? I don't know if they do something different or not.

Comment: @Dekike in that case,`setDT` is better